# How to show all revision(s) of current node?

Tags: views, 8

I try to use filter criteria. It has filtering option with ID but I don't know how to use the current ID of Node.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a view with Show as "Content Revisions" like below [image]

and select fields that are necessary to show. And under Relationship select Content under `Content revision` category.
[image]

And in contextual filters provide the default value for Content ID in URL.
[image]
After saving view goto blocks and enable it in node pages where you want to display.